# I don't even know where to begin with this loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

So the question is:

Create a function called 'reversedLooper' that will be passed one parameter, which will be an array. The function will loop through the array backwards and do the following:

Subtract 2 from the last element

Subtract 1 from the second to last element

Subtract 0 from to the third to last element

Add one to the fourth to last element

Add 2 to the fifth to last.

Continue increasing the amount added by 1, until it reaches the front of the array.

Return the modified array when you are done

All I really know how to do is create a basic loop and subtract by one on all of them. I don't know how to specifically access the second to last element or any particular element. I also don't know where to begin to increase amount added by 1. Let me know if you have any suggestions on starting this problem.

Comment: Just use another variable as the number to subtract/add, EG ˙int j = -2` and increment in every loop, EG `++j`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that in the following way

```js
function doOperation(arr){
    let x = arr.length -2;
    return arr.map(e => {
        x=x-1;
        return e+x;
    } )
}

console.log(doOperation([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]));
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! Now to try and figure out what it all means. I understand (I think) that arr.length -2 will get us to the second to last array. Is there any way you could clarify what is happening on the last 3 lines after that? Thanks!

Comment: x denotes the value we would have to add from the beginning of the array

Comment: hence at each step I decrease it by 1, map would just replace the value in the array. If the element was e, it would become e+x

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

var looper = function(arrayOfNumbers) {

    // number you'll start substracting with
    var substract = 3;

    // loop from last to first element in array
    for (var i = arrayOfNumbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        // substract from i-th element
        arrayOfNumbers[i] -= substract;

        // decrease by 1
       substract--;
    }  

    return arrayOfNumbers;
}

// will output [ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3 ]
console.log(looper(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping a variable with the amount to add to the array, set it to -2 initially, then increase it every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function reversedLooper(array){
    var subtract=-2;
    for(var i=array.length-1;i>=0;i++){
        array[i]=array[i]+subtract
        subtract=subtract+1;
    }
  return array;
}
```